# Dragging of element goes wrong when the container is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/xzkby36n/12/), I made the red container draggable. As you can see, this is working fine but when the green container (*parent container*) is scrolled a bit and then the red container is dragged, the dragging is not happening at correct position.

Can someone please tell me what could be the problem?

I tried `e.pageX`, `e.clientX` and `e.offsetX` but still couldn't able to fix this. (*or maybe I missed something*)

Comment: consider scrolltop while dragging

Comment: Or add jQuery UI's draggable which doesn't have the problem.

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz considered that too.. I will check it again..

Comment: @j08691 If I fix this single bug, everything will be working fine but still I will consider your suggestion when this wastes more time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the scrolling top position to your shape. If you want your square stay on the correct position check that:

```
function repositionShape(e) {
    $self = repositionStart.self;
    $commentSection = repositionStart.commentSection;

    var dy = $('.wrapper').scrollTop(); // Get wrapper scroll position

    $self.css({
    'left': e.clientX - repositionStart.offset.left,
        'top': e.clientY - repositionStart.offset.top +dy // Add delta to your square position
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this.. didn't work. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/xzkby36n/14/).

Comment: Just change the repositionShape function ! [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzkby36n/15/)

Comment: Hi, now I am trying to resize that shape element. I had already written the resize functionality but due to change in layout, everything messed up. For your understanding, I wrote a short self explaining code. Please have a look at it if you want to. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/xzkby36n/19/). (_I kept the wrapper container scrolled to a bit by default_).